# Sharing variables between two background scripts in a Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, scope, firefox-addon

Let's propose I have the following `manifest.json` file:

```
{

    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Test Extension",
    "version": "1.0",

    "icons": {
      "48": "icons/favicon-48x48.png",
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "cookies",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background/background.js", "background/partners.js"]
    }
}
```

If I define a variable in `background.js` like this: `var testVariable = 'test';`, is there any way I can access this same variable in `partners.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's possible. All background scripts run within the same context - *background page*. So any variable globally defined (i.e. at topmost level or via `window.varname`) in a background script is available to any other background script via `window.varname` or just `varname`.

It's like with regular web page: if it has multiple JS scripts, they all share globally defined variables in each of them.

Comment: Okay, I found my error... naturally, the order that I add these files to the array, is not irrelevant:P

Comment: Sure, the order of files matters, at least for code executing immediately.

Comment: You could upvote my answer as well if it solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

Through the manifest? No way.

Only by creating a 3rd js file and calling it where required like so...

```
<script src="shared.js"></script>
```